# Drawing a text returned from a class causes program stop without errors

Tags: c++, crash, sfml

It just crashes whenever I try to draw the text object that's returned from the `FPS_Counter` class.

I've cross-referenced the SFML Documentation, and as far as I could tell, I didn't miss anything, and Visual isn't giving me any nags for bad code either.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//takes frame render time and counts how many of those fits in a second
//then assigns that to a text object and returns it.
class FPS_Counter 
{
private:
    sf::Text text;
    unsigned int count = 0;
public:
    FPS_Counter() //setting up my fps counting object here
    {
        sf::Font font;
        if (!font.loadFromFile("pixel font 1.ttf")) { throw "Cannot find font 'pixel font 1.ttf'."; }
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setCharacterSize(24);
        text.setColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 0, 255));
    }
    sf::Text Count(sf::Time difference)
    {
        cout << "count called" << endl;
        if (difference.asSeconds() != 0) //dodging a divide by zero
        {
            count = 1 / (float)difference.asSeconds();
            text.setString("FPS: " + count);
            cout << "count returned number" << endl;
            return text;
        }
        text.setString("FPS: 0");
        cout << "count returned default" << endl;
        return text;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int mon_res_x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int mon_res_y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(mon_res_x, mon_res_y), "SFML     works!");
    window.setPosition(sf::Vector2i(0,0));

    FPS_Counter fps;
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time time;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();

        time = clock.getElapsedTime(); //get time since last frame
        clock.restart();

        window.draw(fps.Count(time)); //draw fps count with given frame-time

        window.display();

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The basic exemple given at the end of the installation tutorial worked?

Comment: And you're not using the exeption catching here, how can you be sure that your font has laoded?

Comment: Well it's not throwing in the console, so I assume it's loading fine, because when I tried to load a non-unicode font previously it would crash before getting to Count() and writing 'count called' in the console.

The code runs fine until after it returns the SFML text object to the draw function back in the main loop. That's where it crashes.

Comment: I think I just solved my own problem. I was adding an unsigned int to a string without converting it, so when I moved the contents of the class to the main loop, it was spouting gibberish from random places in memory on the screen, like paths to includes, random letters etc.

I'm assuming copying that and returning it to a draw call from a class could have been the cause of the crashes.

Comment: Also it appears that SFML is not made for copying entire Text or Graphic classes around, so I have to create the text before the class, and pass the text as a pointer to it.

Comment: THe problm comes from the time comparing, your if condition is always going to be false since you're comparing seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each frame may only take a few miliseconds to render, counting seconds elapsed will always be 0.
You need to make a timer in your fps counter class, and print the FPS text each time this counter reach 0, changing your FPS every frame is useless since it will only be recalculated each second:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//takes frame render time and counts how many of those fits in a second
//then assigns that to a text object and returns it.
class FPS_Counter
{
private:
    sf::Text text;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    sf::Int32 countdown = 1000;
public:
    FPS_Counter() //setting up my fps counting object here
    {
        sf::Font font;
        if (!font.loadFromFile("pixel font 1.ttf")) { throw "Cannot find font 'pixel font 1.ttf'."; }
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setCharacterSize(24);
        text.setColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 0, 255));
    }
    sf::Text Count(sf::Int32 difference)
    {
        countdown -= difference; //Counts the time elapsed
        count++; //Increment FPS
        cout << "count called" << endl;
        if (countdown < 0)
        {
            countdown += 1000;
            text.setString("FPS: " + count);
            cout << "count returned number" << endl;
        }
        return text;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int mon_res_x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int mon_res_y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(mon_res_x, mon_res_y), "SFML     works!");
    window.setPosition(sf::Vector2i(0, 0));

    FPS_Counter fps;
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time time;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();

        time = clock.restart(); //get time since last frame

        window.draw(fps.Count(time.asMilliseconds())); //draw fps count with given frame-time

        window.display();

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also,(IMO) i would recommend sending a pointer of the text to your main class once with an "init" function, it would be easier to handle a fail into the font loading and increase your FPS, this would also separate your timer from your rendering.

Comment: Functionally this solves my problem much better than I even tried to do it. But I was intentionally trying to do an exercise where I wanted the FPS calculated and drawn every frame.

I solved the problem I posed here by avoiding it entirely. Instead of copying the text object to-be-drawn in the render loop, I referenced the target window to the FPS_Counter class to avoid any class copying issues with SFML and let it draw itself to the target window.

Great answer, though, and probably what I will be doing from now on instead!